# How do I embed a custom graphic into a border of a panel using Synth?

Tags: java, user-interface, synth

I'm learning to work with Synth and I'm trying to figure out how to embed a custom png to be used as a border for a panel.

My border.xml looks like this:

```
<synth>  
<style id="PanelStyle">  
<insets top="15" left="20" right="20" bottom="15"/>  
    <state>  
        <imagePainter method="panelBorder" path="test.png" sourceInsets="10 10 10 10" />  
    </state>  
</style>  
<bind style="PanelStyle" type="region" key="Panel" />  
</synth>
```

However, when I set the l&f using that xml, it fills the entire panel up with the png rather than just the edges.

Answer (score 1):

you need to set the paintCenter option of your image painter to false, like this:

```
<imagePainter method="panelBorder" paintCenter="false" path="test.png" sourceInsets="10 10 10 10" />
```

Hopefully that helps. Here's the link to the site I found that at, pretty useful:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/synth/doc-files/synthFileFormat.html